# Xamarin SherlockListFragment

Tags: c#, android, .net, actionbarsherlock, xamarin

im tring to make a List in my application. Im using the SherlockListFragment.
the problem is, that i dont get any error, my App just show me a PopUp with the following message: "Sorry Unfortunately, App_Name has stopped."
Im getting all the Data i need, and the App stops at returning the rootView

Thanks for you help!

The Code looks like this:
Groupsfragment

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.App;

namespace Community_Task_Manager
{
    public class GroupsFragment : SherlockListFragment
    {
        List<TwoLineItem> list_items = new List<TwoLineItem> ();

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater p_layout, ViewGroup p_view, Bundle p_bundle)
        {
            // Set view
            var rootView = p_layout.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListFragment, p_view, false);


            // Get Data from Server
            string jsonToSend;
            DataBaseSendObject dbs = new DataBaseSendObject ();
            dbs.CommandId = 4;
            dbs.AddParameter ("@UserId", Localpreference.GetUserId (Application.Context), 2);
            jsonToSend = dbs.JsonSerialization ();
            object objRecieved;
            objRecieved = DatabaseConnection.SendToServer(dbs);

            // Bringing Items into the right Format
            list_items = BM_JsonSerializer.GetListFromJson<TwoLineItem> (objRecieved.ToString ());
            TwoLineItem createNewGroupe = new TwoLineItem ();
            createNewGroupe.Id = 0;
            createNewGroupe.FirstLine = "Create new Group";
            createNewGroupe.SecondLine = "";


            this.ListAdapter = new TwoLineItemAdapter(Activity, list_items);
            //SetListShown (true);
            // Adding data to the View with an Adapter
            //ListView lst = rootView.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.list);
            //lst.Adapter = new TwoLineItemAdapter(this.Activity, list_itemsss);
            //lst.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;  // to be defined

            return rootView;


        }
}
}
```

ListFragment.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/list" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

TwoLineItem.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/TwoLineItemLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/FirstLine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SecondLine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

TwoLineItem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Community_Task_Manager
{
    class TwoLineItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstLine { get; set; }
        public string SecondLine { get; set; }

    }
}
```

TwoLineItemAdapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Community_Task_Manager
{
    class TwoLineItemAdapter : BaseAdapter<TwoLineItem>
    {
        List<TwoLineItem> items;
        Activity context;
        public TwoLineItemAdapter(Activity context, List<TwoLineItem> items) : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override TwoLineItem this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.TwoLineItem, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.FirstLine).Text = item.FirstLine;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.SecondLine).Text = item.SecondLine;

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you debug / add breakpoints?

Comment: i can and it just stops on Groupsfragment at the Return rootView, i dont get an error in the xamarin studio, just on my Phone the popup message "Sorry Unfortunately, App_Name has stopped.

Comment: Is there anything you can see in the adb logcat? is it in the debug console that you are seeing that "Sorry... " message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot, in all of my implementations of the SherlockListFragment, I have found none that I had to inflate the list view itself. In all of my implementations I simply define the adapter for the list in the OnActivityCreated method. In short my code looks like this

```
    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);            
        SetHasOptionsMenu(true); 
         if (_adapter == null)
            _adapter = new SkillAdapter(Activity, MyApp, MyCharacter); //MyCustom Adapter class.
        ListAdapter = _adapter;
        ListView.OnItemLongClickListener = _adapter;               

    }
```

or

```
    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);    
        // Get Data from Server
        string jsonToSend;
        DataBaseSendObject dbs = new DataBaseSendObject ();
        dbs.CommandId = 4;
        dbs.AddParameter ("@UserId", Localpreference.GetUserId (Application.Context), 2);
        jsonToSend = dbs.JsonSerialization ();
        object objRecieved;
        objRecieved = DatabaseConnection.SendToServer(dbs);

        // Bringing Items into the right Format
        list_items = BM_JsonSerializer.GetListFromJson<TwoLineItem> (objRecieved.ToString ());
        TwoLineItem createNewGroupe = new TwoLineItem ();
        createNewGroupe.Id = 0;
        createNewGroupe.FirstLine = "Create new Group";
        createNewGroupe.SecondLine = "";

        ListAdapter = new TwoLineItemAdapter(Activity, list_items);
        //SetListShown (true);
        // Adding data to the View with an Adapter
        //ListView lst = rootView.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.list);
        //lst.Adapter = new TwoLineItemAdapter(this.Activity, list_itemsss);
        //lst.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;  // to be defined




    }
```

Since it's a specific Fragment I believe Sherlock does this other stuff behind the scenes.  All you need to do is define your adapter, and then set the ListAdapter to your defined adapter. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks i found a solution without the inflate but i coudnt find the time to post it yet. Ill try to post my solution later and ill compare yours with mine.